# how to save an ID in file just once?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm Working in this program almost like for 7 hours but i do not know where I'm doing wrong if you could help me I really appreciate it . The program is not suppose to accept the same ID twice .My problem is that when i enter a curator Id , name and save it .If i enter the same Id again it will saves and it says "Curator ID Saved Thank you"

```
  private void SaveCuratorBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        curator Curator = new curator();

        try
        {
            Curator.ID = CuratorIDbox.Text;
            bool sameid = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < curatorlist.Count; i++)
            {
                if (curatorlist[i].ID == Curator.ID)
                {
                    sameid = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sameid)
                MessageBox.Show("ID already exist please try again !");
            else
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CuratorIDbox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CuratorNamebox.Text))
                    MessageBox.Show("please do not leave Boxes empty!");
                else
                {


                    curatorlist.add(Curator);
                    savefile();
                }
            }



        }


        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
        try
        {

            Curator.NAME = CuratorNamebox.Text;
            MessageBox.Show("Curator Saved Thank You");
            savefile();
            CuratorIDbox.Text = "";
            CuratorNamebox.Text = "";

        }

        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to say without debugging. I don't see anything wrong with the logic other than the whole thing living inside a try/catch. You should only try/catch something that is known to throw an exception.

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the curatorlist on entry to the method?

Comment: My guess is that curatorlist is empty.

Comment: Set a breakpoint and follow it to see what happens. Btw that for loop could be replaced with one line of LINQ.

Comment: Well, your code to display the "Curator saved Thank you" is outside of the range of the same name checking ... so it will save no matter what.

Comment: @Ian H Can you explain it a bit more plz

Comment: Of course it says! It's in another try...catch block. Nothing hinders that line executing. Not an if or a return or anything...

Answer (score 1):

Without debugging, I would refactor your code like this:

```
private void SaveCuratorBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CuratorIDbox.Text) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(CuratorNamebox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("please do not leave Boxes empty!");
        return; // If one of the textboxes is empty, we don't continue executing the method
    }

    curator Curator = new curator();
    Curator.ID = CuratorIDbox.Text;
    bool sameid = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < curatorlist.Count; i++)
    {
        if (curatorlist[i].ID == Curator.ID)
        {
            sameid = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (sameid)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ID already exist please try again !");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Curator.NAME = CuratorNamebox.Text;

        // I suppose your savefile method can throw exceptions... this has to be in a try-catch block then
        try
        {
            savefile();
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Curator Saved Thank You");
        CuratorIDbox.Text = "";
        CuratorNamebox.Text = "";
    }
}
```

One suggestion:
Checking for already existing curators I would use the following line:

```
if (curatorlist.Any(c => c == Curator.ID)) { ... } else { ... }
```

(you can exchange your for loop with this)

Comment: just fixed it man Thank you for taking your time to answering my Question